# How make the font become big then become small after few sec?

Tags: java, swing

I wan to make the text big then become small again after few second and it will keep repeating become big then small. How should i code it?

//DUMMY POST nfinity Blade is a fighting game developed by Chair Entertainment and Epic Games and released through the App Store on December 9, 2010. It is the first iOS video game to run on the Unreal Engine. In the game, the unnamed player character fights a series of one-on-one battles in a derelict castle to face the immortal God King. When in battle, players swipe the screen to attack and parry, and tap the screen to dodge and block enemy attacks. Upon victory or defeat, the player restarts the game as the character's descendant with the same items and experience level. Developed by a team of twelve people, the game was intended to demonstrate the new iOS version of the Unreal Engine. Four free expansions added new equipment, endings, and game modes. The game made US$1.6 million in the//DUMMYPOST

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class FontSizeAnimation extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
 Timer timer;
int x = 1;
 float alpha = 1;

 public FontSizeAnimation() {
  timer = new Timer(4, this);
  timer.setInitialDelay(500);
 timer.start();
 }

public void paint(Graphics g) {
super.paintComponent(g);
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

Font font = new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, x);
g2d.setFont(font);

FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
String s = "Java";

int w = (int) getSize().getWidth();
int h = (int) getSize().getHeight();

int stringWidth = fm.stringWidth(s);

g2d.drawString(s, (w - stringWidth) / 2, h / 2);
}

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  JFrame frame = new JFrame("FontSizeAnimation");
 frame.add(new FontSizeAnimation());
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setSize(400, 300);
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setVisible(true);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
x += 1;
alpha -= 0.0001;
repaint();
 }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course there are multiple ways of achieving this, but you could create a variable that holds wheter the size of the font should get bigger or smaller. Update that variable in the `actionPerformed()` method and then change the font size according to what the variable's value is. Here's an example with your code (click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQP1F.gif) for a preview, would be too distracting in the post):

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class FontSizeAnimation extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    Timer timer;
    int x = 1;
    int lastX = 1;
    float alpha = 1;
    boolean bigger;

    public FontSizeAnimation() {
        timer = new Timer(4, this);
        timer.setInitialDelay(500);
        timer.start();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        Font font = new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, x);
        g2d.setFont(font);

        FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
        String s = "Java";

        int w = (int) getSize().getWidth();
        int h = (int) getSize().getHeight();

        int stringWidth = fm.stringWidth(s);

        g2d.drawString(s, (w - stringWidth) / 2, h / 2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("FontSizeAnimation");
        frame.add(new FontSizeAnimation());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (x > 50) {
            bigger = false;
        } else if (x < 2) {
            bigger = true;
        }
        if (bigger) {
            x++;
        } else {
            x--;
        }
        alpha -= 0.0001;
        repaint();
    }

}
```